# How to print backtrace of main thread while in other thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, backtrace

How to print backtrace of main thread while in other thread?

while in other thread,I want to print the backtrace of main thread.is there any sanple code for me?

Comment: Take a look at KSCrash.

Comment: @Avi I didn't want to import 3rd framework, is there any sanple code

Comment: Why don't you look at the project and note, that 1) the source is available, and 2) it has sample code.  If you want someone to write your code for you, just say so, and we can close the question now.

Comment: @Avi Yes，You are right,I will take a look at KSCrash for the future,because my application is face deadline tonight, I have no time to look at the project source code .

Comment: @Avi I did went through the KSCrash repo and the code which does this and it does not actually give out the stack trace of the main thread which is the only thing OP asked for. Leaving this here so no one else goes down that rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   NSLog(@"Trace = %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
});
```

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to print the stacktrace of the current instruction pointer in the main thread.  I can't think why he wants to do this, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe YES, I want to make a tool which can know the main thread is block,and print the callStack of the main thread. if do by dispatch_async ,the stack is "[NSThread callStackSymbols]",it's not which I want

Comment: @SubCycle You won't get it.

Answer (score 0):

check this code (GPLv3)：[BSBacktraceLogger](https://github.com/bestswifter/BSBacktraceLogger/blob/master/BSBacktraceLogger/BSBacktraceLogger.m)

```
+ (NSString *)bs_backtraceOfCurrentThread {
    return [self bs_backtraceOfNSThread:[NSThread currentThread]];
}

+ (NSString *)bs_backtraceOfMainThread {
    return [self bs_backtraceOfNSThread:[NSThread mainThread]];
}
```